# 'dict' object has no such attribution error - basic python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, attributes

I have created a function under a class, and trying to call that function on a read txt file. More specifically,
Loop over the "student objects" and call the "print_myself" method on each of them. the output of the row iteration looks ok, but when I try calling the function on the output of the row iteration, it gives me an attribution error - and I can't seem to fix it myself.

I attached the class, function code as well, could anyone please help me out?
Thank you

SOLVED

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,status,gpa):
        self.firstname = firstname 
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.status = status
        self.gpa = gpa
        
    def print_myself(self):
        print("Original student information")
        print("First Name:\t{}".format(self.firstname))
        print("Last Name:\t{}".format(self.lastname))
        print("Status:\t{}".format(self.status))
        print("GPA:\t{}".format(self.gpa))
```

Iterated over the rows of the table and create a student object for each of the data entries, store the student objects on a list "students".

ORIGINAL

```
import pandas as pd

students = []
data = pd.read_csv('students.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    students.append({'firstname':row['firstname'],
                     'lastname':row['lastname'],
                     'status':row['status'],
                     'gpa':row['gpa']})

print(students)
Student.print_myself(student)
```

Fixed

```
students = []
data = pd.read_csv('students.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print( df)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    students.append(Student(**{'firstname':row['firstname'],
                           'lastname':row['lastname'],
                           'status':row['status'],
                           'gpa':row['gpa']}))
for i in range (0,10):
    students[i].print_myself()
```

OUTPUT of print(students)

```
Original student information
First Name: Mike
Last Name:  Barnes
Status: freshman
GPA:    4.0
Original student information
First Name: Jim
Last Name:  Nickerson
Status: sophomore
GPA:    3.0
Original student information,....
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems: `print_myself` is an instance method, so you need an instance of the class like `Student()`.

That is, instead of:

```
Student.print_myself(student)
```

I'd suggest:

```
students[0].print_myself()
```

The second is when adding to students, in the line `students.append`, you're appending a `dict` object, but it should be first converted to a `Student` object.

So for example, this line:

```py
students.append({'firstname':row['firstname'],
                     'lastname':row['lastname'],
                     'status':row['status'],
                     'gpa':row['gpa']})
```

I'd suggest trying it like:

```py
students.append(Student(**row))
```

Or, to be safer:

```py
students.append(Student(**{'firstname':row['firstname'],
                           'lastname':row['lastname'],
                           'status':row['status'],
                           'gpa':row['gpa']}))
```

Comment: To give a little clarification as what "needing an instance" means here: Calling class methods without an instance is totally valid syntax, except `self` will not be automatically passed from an instance since there is none. In OP's code they're doing `self=students`, thus the error.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after trying revising the code by the suggestion:(. I don't think Student(**row) is an option bc it recognizes as I am putting in argument

Comment: @riven did you try the second suggestion? i.e. with Student(**{'firstname'...})

Comment: @rv.kvetch I did try it. it reads it as if the (**.. ) part is an argument

Comment: it is, actually. the **.. syntax converts the dict object to keyword arguments that are passed in to the constructor, same as like Student(firstname=...)

Comment: @riven would you be able to update your question with the code you've tested with? might be easier to spot any issues that way.

Comment: true true, just updated with the updated script and new error:(. I can't seem to find a way to fix, tho I do think I am probably missing something simple but important

Comment: @riven  think I found the error. It's a typo, the constructor should be called `__init__` instead of `__int__`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch fixed! updated the question with fixed script. thank you so much!

Comment: @rv.kvetch I can't believe I missed init__ .. haha

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated a new object of class Student

Comment: isn't that already included in the class student: ? should I write another line? thank you